# Changing the search results destination URL

Tags: search

Sorry for the basic question, every Google query I try yields no useful results.

How do I change the search results directory in Wordpress? Currently all searches need to be on the `root` to produce results. i.e.

`www.domain.tld/?s=query`

But I'd like to be able to have two searches (which I currently already have working independently):

- `www.domain.tld/blog/?s=query`
- `www.domain.tld/somethingelse/?s=query`

I've tried adding the directories to my search form `action`s, and although I've got Wordpress loading the right template for each search, the searches never produce any results. They only produce results when searching on the `root`.

---

So it turns out that coming back to this I was able to just include the directory in the search form action. The strange this is that I'd experimented with this at quite some length - and gotten nowhere. So I think that something else might have been at play preventing this from working for some reason. Annoying mystery!

Comment: You mean you wants some sort of custom search? or just change url look?

Comment: I mean I want the query to execute on a specific path.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new page. Let's say you want to have:
`http://example.com/mysearch/`

Create a page that will have that URL structure.
Next, Search form -> Go to and on you search form action do:

```
<form role="filter-search" method="get" id="sd_searchform_filter" action="<?php 
    echo home_url( '/mysearch/' ); ?>">...
```

Now go to `functions.php` (or where you want this function)
and now we doing tricks!

```
function isu_search_url( $query ) {

    $page_id = 12; // This is ID of page with your structure -> http://example.com/mysearch/
    $per_page = 10;
    $post_type = 'activity'; // I just modify a bit this querry

    // Now we must edit only query on this one page
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->queried_object->ID == $page_id  ) {
        // I like to have additional class if it is special Query like for activity as you can see
        add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
            $classes[] = 'filter-search';
            return $classes;
        } );
        $query->set( 'pagename', '' ); // we reset this one to empty!
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page ); // set post per page or dont ... :)
            $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type ); // we set post type if we need (I need in this case)
            // 3 important steps (make sure to do it, and you not on archive page, 
            // or just fails if it is archive, use e.g. Query monitor plugin )
            $query->is_search = true; // We making WP think it is Search page 
            $query->is_page = false; // disable unnecessary WP condition
            $query->is_singular = false; // disable unnecessary WP condition
        }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'isu_search_url' );
```

Now it works, you don't have to change `.htaccess`, etc.
Pagination will work properly. :)

Comment: This was VERY helpful! :)

Comment: This works great! I'm noticing that on the homepage it's throwing a —

"Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object" error on the homepage. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `$query->queried_object->ID` might be a problem, just try add condition also to check if $`query->queried_object` exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with functions.php file:

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

also possible via htacces rules:

```
# search redirect
# this will take anything in the query string, minus any extraneous values, and turn them into a clean working url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

[source](http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks Amir, I'll take a look at the first option later today. I can't do a rewrite as I'm actually using the site index for a truly static html page (very specific and unusual setup) which is why I can't have the search execute there, so merely rewriting it won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Amir, I haven't gotten round to implementing this suggestion yet - but just looking at it - isn't this just redirecting the query to a place where the search won't work? i.e. how is this any different to just using `/search/` as part of the form action?

Comment: Ok so this is weird - before I even attempted to implement this solution I had a quick fiddle with the action again. For some reason running the search on a different sub directory is *now working*. This is particularly strange as I'd experimented with this already with no luck, even trying to re-save the permalink settings to force things into action. Is there something obvious that may have stopped and started this from working??

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Getting a 404 with the PHP version of this.